# Adding in joined data to a query result

Tags: sql, oracle

This may already be here but it's understandably difficult to search for. Basically, I have a main table, Companies, with a CompanyID. I have to tables that join to it - Users, and Contractors. A company may have multiple users, it may have multiple contractors. But users and contractors have no relation to each other.

What I want is to have a list of all the users and all the contractors for a company, like this:

```
Company1    User1    Contractor1
Company1    User2    Contractor2
Company2    User3    Contractor1
Company2    User4    NULL
Company3    User5    Contractor2
Company3    NULL     Contractor3
```

etc. In the above, Company1 has two users and two contractors, Company2 has two users and one contractor, Company3 has one user and two contractors.

I'm at a loss of if this is possible to recreate in a pure single SQL query. If I were using PHP, it would be easy - I would just pull it all into an array and create subarrays. But I'm attempting to do this in Logi Info, and while I've so far been unable to figure out how to do it in Logi's objects, I was hoping maybe I could just straight do it in the SQL.

Is this possible? Joins will typically include duplicates that are difficult to weed out; for example, for Company1, it would have four rows, User1-Contractor1, User1-Contractor2, User2-Contractor1, and User2-Contractor2. And I can't think of a method to group by since it would require a unique combination (which already exists) or it would remove the wrong thing, like having User1 repeated with two different contractors, and omitting User2 entirely.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH indexed_users AS (
  SELECT u.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Company_ID ORDER BY Name ) AS idx
  FROM Users u
),
indexed_contractors AS (
  SELECT c.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Company_ID ORDER BY Name ) AS idx
  FROM Contractors c
),
indexed_users_and_contractors AS (
  SELECT COALESCE( u.Company_ID, c.Company_ID ) AS Company_ID,
         u.Name AS UserName,
         c.Name AS ContractorName,
         COALESCE( u.idx, c.idx ) AS idx
  FROM   indexed_users u
         FULL OUTER JOIN
         indexed_contractors c
         ON ( u.Company_id = c.Company_ID
             AND u.idx = c.idx )
  ORDER BY 4
)
SELECT c.Name,
       i.UserName,
       i.ContractorName
FROM   Companies c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       indexed_users_and_contractors i
       ON ( c.Company_ID = i.Company_ID )
ORDER BY c.Name, i.idx
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/480aa/3/0)**:

```
|     NAME | USERNAME | CONTRACTORNAME |
|----------|----------|----------------|
| Company1 |    User1 |    Contractor1 |
| Company1 |    User2 |    Contractor2 |
| Company2 |    User3 |    Contractor1 |
| Company2 |    User4 |         (null) |
| Company3 |    User5 |    Contractor2 |
| Company3 |   (null) |    Contractor3 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can, although it is somewhat unnatural.

```
SELECT usr.name
      ,cont.name
      ,nvl(usr.comp_id,cont.comp_id)
      ,comp.name
FROM (SELECT id, name, comp_id, row_number() over (partition by comp_id order by id) rn from usr) usr 
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT id, name, comp_id, row_number() over (partition by comp_id order by id) rn from cont) cont
  ON (cont.comp_id = usr.comp_id
      AND cont.rn = usr.rn)
JOIN comp
  ON (comp.id = nvl(usr.comp_id,cont.comp_id))
ORDER BY nvl(usr.comp_id,cont.comp_id)
```