# Oracle SQL: Can I combine columns from different tables into one table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I wonder if I can combine columns from different tables into one results.

```
Table A:
ID ColA ColB
1   A    B

Table B:
ID ColC ColD ColE
1   C1   D1   E1
1   C2   D2   E2

Table C:
ID ColF ColG 
1   F    G
```

Expected Results:

```
ID ColA ColB ColC ColD ColE ColF ColG
1   A    B    C1   D1   E1   F    G
1             C2   D2   E2
```

Is there a way to combine columns from different tables into one?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why in `Table B` for the both the rows `ID` is 1

Comment: Is this a question asking how to use JOIN clauses in Oracle? That's here: http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj29840.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding in joined data to a query result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29637299/adding-in-joined-data-to-a-query-result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I 'simple' solution would be a `full outer join`, however, that would not give you the gaps you have for the second row (because TableA only contains 1 row).

So, to solve that, you can make it a little more complex and generate numbers per ID for each of the tables. Then you can make a full outer join on each of those subselects, and use that generated row number as the second field in the join. That way, you won't get a cartesian product, and you'll get the result as you drew it, with gaps for missing rows.

I don't have a database at hand to test it, but let me know if it works.

```
 select
    coalesce(A.ID, B.ID, C.ID) as ID,
    A.ColA, A.ColB, B.ColC, B.ColD, B.ColE, C.ColF, C.ColG
 from
    (select
      ID,
      row_number() over (partition by ID order by ColA) as rownumber,
      ColA,
      ColB
    from
      TableA t) A
  full outer join
    (select
      ID,
      row_number() over (partition by ID order by ColC) as rownumber,
      ColC,
      ColD,
      ColE
    from
      TableB t) B on B.ID = A.ID and B.rownumer = A.rownumber
  full outer join
    (select
      ID,
      row_number() over (partition by ID order by ColF) as rownumber,
      ColF,
      ColG
    from
      TableC t) C on C.ID = nvl(A.ID, B.ID) and C.rownumer = A.rownumber
```

Answer (score 0):

You could join them using a `Full Outer Join`. This could be done using the ID column, or by exposing the rownum value for each row.

According to your desired results, it appears that you actually need ID to be unique. You would need to change TABLE B to have unique values in the ID column.

```
...
Table B:
ID ColC ColD ColE
1   C1   D1   E1
2   C2   D2   E2 //ID COLUMN VALUE CHANGED FROM 1 to 2 to be unique
...
```

If ID is unique, you can do a Full Outer Join using ID:

```
select a.*,b.*,c.*
from a 
full outer join b on a.ID = b.ID
full outer join c on c.ID = b.ID
```

Otherwise you could do a Full Outer Join using `rownum`:

```
select a.*,b.*,c.*
from (select t.*,rownum as RowNumber from a) a
full outer join (select t.*,rownum as RowNumber from b) b on a.RowNumber = b.RowNumber
full outer join (select t.*,rownum as RowNumber from c) c on c.RowNumber = b.RowNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID AS "ID", ColA AS "ColA", ColB AS "ColB",NULL AS ColC ,NULL AS ColD ,NULL AS ColE, NULL AS ColF, NULL AS ColG FROM Table A
UNION
SELECT ID AS "ID", NULL AS "ColA", NULL AS "ColB",ColC AS "ColC" ,ColD AS "ColD" ,ColE AS "ColE", NULL AS ColF, NULL AS ColG FROM Table B
UNION
SELECT ID AS "ID", NULL AS "ColA", NULL AS "ColB",NULL AS "ColC" ,NULL AS "ColD" ,NULL AS "ColE", ColF AS "ColF", ColG AS "ColG" FROM Table C
```

Hope this is what you expected